# Slick Slider Styling

Tags: javascript, html, css, slick.js

I am trying to use Slick Slider to replicate this wireframe (attached)[image]

I have set up a code pen and got the slider into a fairly decent state but stumped with how position the buttons as per the slider. I also think the way I have set up the height and width to overflow off screen is not correct. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

https://codepen.io/mattrees92/pen/wvddGgK

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
<h1> Hello </h1>
<p> Here is an example of a slider we can use for Gaggia. Content block will be on    the left with slider on the right </p>
<button> Click Me </button>
</div>
<div class="col-md-8">
<div class="slider">
<div>
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1446770145316-10a05382c470?dpr=1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&h=450&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=" alt="">
</div>
<div>
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1455717974081-0436a066bb96?dpr=1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&h=450&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=" alt="">
</div>
<div>
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1477420086945-b99c643e8a3d?dpr=1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&h=450&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=" alt="">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

```
  outline: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.slider {
  display: flex;
}

.slick-track {
  will-change: transform;
}

.slick-list {
  overflow: hidden;
  will-change: transform;
}

.slick-slide {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 20px;
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1));
}

.slick-slide img {
  height: 100vh;
  max-height: 80vh;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  object-fit: cover;
}

[type="button"] {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 0;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  background-color: black;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.9;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  transition: all 0.25s ease;
}

.slick-next {
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
}

.slick-prev {
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've adjusted the `top`, `left` properties to bring the arrow buttons according to the design: https://codepen.io/tilwinjoy/pen/WNjjoQr

I highly recommend using CSS variables instead of hardcoded pixel values.

```js
// Slick slider init

$('.slider').slick({
  arrows: true,
  dots: false,
  infinite: true,
  speed: 500,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  centerMode: false,
  variableWidth: true,
  draggable: true
});
```

```css
* {
  outline: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.slider {
  display: flex;
}

.slick-track {
  will-change: transform;
}

.slick-list {
  overflow: hidden;
  will-change: transform;
}

.slick-slide {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 20px;
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1));
}

.slick-slide img {
  height: 100vh;
  max-height: 80vh;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  object-fit: cover;
}

[type="button"] {
  position: fixed;
  top: 102%;
  left: 20px;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 0;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  background-color: black;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.9;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  transition: all 0.25s ease;
}

.slick-next {
  left: 82px;
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
}

.slick-prev {
  left: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.6.0/slick.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.0.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <h1> Hello </h1>
      <p> Here is an example of a slider we can use for Gaggia. Content block will be on the left with slider on the right </p>
      <button> Click Me </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="slider">
        <div>
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1446770145316-10a05382c470?dpr=1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&h=450&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=" alt="">
        </div>
        <div>
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1455717974081-0436a066bb96?dpr=1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&h=450&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=" alt="">
        </div>
        <div>
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1477420086945-b99c643e8a3d?dpr=1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&h=450&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did try this mate, put it in the right position but seemed to overlap my next container when scaling the screen size.